# Arch Linux: Running VirtualBox (VM) without a window manager

Tags: x11, xorg, virtualbox, xinit

In *Arch Linux*, I would like to run VirtualBox without a window manager.

As a root I can easily do:

```
xinit /usr/bin/VirtualBox  -- :0 vt1
```

As a non-root user I get a blank screen.  If I open another terminal, kill VirtualBox and read

```
~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log  ,
```

then it does not show any error and is basically the same as the `"/var/log/Xorg.0.log"` I get as a root.

*UPDATE*

As noted by Arkadiusz Drabczyk, the problem was with a bug in VB. It works with version 5.2.4-119785.
My final objective is to use VB kind of bare-metal, starting an OS in fullscreen and nothing else, that is:

```
xinit '/usr/bin/VirtualBox' --startvm "VM name" --fullscreen -- :0 vt1
```

Comment: if you don't need the GUI at all, `VBoxHeadless --startvm vmName` should do the trick.  (... come to think of it, a `--startvm WhatVMDoYouWantToStart` argument is probably the missing ingredient.)

Comment: @quixotic: of course this is for simplicity. Actual command should be something like: `xinit /usr/bin/VirtualBox --startvm  "vm name"  --fullscreen  -- :0 vt1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember I was able to reproduce your problem with not being able to
run `Virtualbox` as non-root user without window manager with older versions of `Virtualbox`
but it works for me with `5.2.4-119785`.

However, as stated in the comments you don't need to graphical interface at all.  `Virtualbox`  comes with command line interface, it's my preferred method of interacting with it. Say, to list virtual machines:

```
$ vboxmanage list vms
"ubuntu" {e7fe8912-5484-4b9d-b5fe-431ae648b2dd}
"slackware64-current" {a00e1925-9cb6-4330-8b04-bbce69b49c67}
"slackware-current" {636b85f2-1e02-497b-9c50-22eb285250a3}
"freebsd" {acb77ca6-b051-400a-92bb-b3b2f1905991}
"openindiana" {bdca01dd-ea5d-4323-9fd2-92665d311bda}
"slackware64-14.1" {f9db3ba6-2316-4f92-8264-4abc8e4f71b3}
"slackware-14.2" {ccb5ddba-4ea1-4469-8ebc-21c84b8ca825}
"slackware-14.1-pathes-test" {67bec56d-b7d5-4427-a726-de2b4c1ba700}
"Slackware_new_test" {2e9232b5-bab1-41fc-8db4-ff4aab56f94c}
"slackware64-14.2" {2084cd19-d286-48b5-8e7b-3d1bb7a94d93}
"alpine linux" {be56c6a7-5821-4815-984b-6b40a6367acb}
"openwrt_Chaos_Calmer" {a4fcb438-dfc7-4672-8976-0d21b34357e0}
"linux-mint" {6e5e99d8-2dd8-4798-93ac-ffbf14c6c9db}
```

To start a virtual machine:

```
$ vboxmanage startvm "slackware64-14.1" --type headless
```

You can then access a started virtual machine with `ssh`, `telnet` etc.

To remove a virtual machine:

```
$ vboxmanage unregistervm "slackware64-14.1" -delete
```

To show info on a given virtual machine:

```
$ vboxmanage showvminfo slackware64-14.1
```

To stop a virtual machine:

```
$ vboxmanage controlvm slackware64-14.1 poweroff
```

You can even create a new virtual machine in command line: https://gist.github.com/ardrabczyk/65b68d0121f2964cd99e

Comment: Thank you, but I actually wrote without a Window Manager, not without a window/GUI

Comment: I know, I said that I was able to reproduce your problem on my system. Try upgrading `virtualbox` if possible.

Comment: Sorry, read too fast. After `pacman -Syu` I can run `xinit /usr/bin/VirtualBox  -- :0 vt1`, but I am unable to pass parameters to VirtualBox. I would run a VM with: ` xinit /usr/bin/VirtualBox --startvm "VM name" --fullscreen -- :0 vt1 `, but I get only the VirtualBox main app.

Comment: I'm confused. You asked about `xinit /usr/bin/VirtualBox  -- :0 vt1` in your question. Does `virtualbox` now show up?

Comment: Yes, _it works_ thanks to your suggestion to upgrade. Now I would like to run a VM, not only the VirtualBox main app. For this I need to pass some parameters to  VirtualBox (or use VBoxManage). It works putting `/usr/bin/VirtualBox --startvm "VM name" --fullscreen` in `.xinitrc`. I was wondering if I can pass VB parameters straight from xinit.

Comment: How about `xinit '/usr/bin/VirtualBox --startvm "VM name" --fullscreen' -- :0 vt1`? I didn't try that.

Comment: xinit says "No such a file or directory." It considers all material inside the single quotes as a path.   `xinit /usr/bin/VirtualBox '--startvm "VM name" --fullscreen' -- :0 vt1` does not work either (it opens VB window only)

Comment: This works for me: `xinit  '/usr/bin/VirtualBox' --startvm "VM name" --fullscreen -- :0 vt1`

Answer (score 3):

I found several options.

1. [`VBoxManage`](https://superuser.com/a/1153941/245595)

   ```
   VBoxManage startvm "VM name" --type headless
   ```
2. [`VBoxHeadless`](https://superuser.com/a/1153941/245595)

   ```
   VBoxHeadless --startvm <uuid|name>
   ```

And bear in mind `xinit ...`, [as you already know](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410233/arch-linux-running-virtualbox-without-a-window-manager/411913#comment735004_410233).

See also:

https://superuser.com/questions/135498/run-virtualbox-in-background-without-a-window

https://superuser.com/questions/1153939/start-a-vm-in-virtualbox-without-gui

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=66058

Comment: Thank you, but I actually wrote without a Window Manager, not without a window/GUI